# How I can change lightmaps at runtime in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

How to change the backed light maps for different layouts ? 
Here I am using two architecture models
Each architecture models has different objects when try to switch the layouts the light maps are not get changing so how to change the light maps when loading the new layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightmaps are most commonly applied to static objects in applications that use real-time 3D computer graphics, such as video games, in order to provide lighting effects such as global illumination at a relatively low computational cost.

If you want your shadows to change dynamicaly, you need to make your objects dynamic and apply dynamic light to them. Because lightmaps are built only in editor. The only way to change them in unity realtime is to switch different baked lightmaps.

There is an example on community with sample classes.
This example shows you how to switch between day and night lightmaps, but you can use it for your own purposes. You can read more about it here: [LightMapSwitcher](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/LightMapSwitcher)

Comment: @MickyD Lightmaps are baked in editor using static lightning. The only way to change them in real time is to switch different baked lightmaps. Otherwise OP should use realtime lights

Comment: My original comment is based on your original post.  Agreed

Comment: Mark Benovsky Thanks!... so here I want to access my lightmap dataset or textures?

Comment: You can switch built lightmap textures

Comment: I used the script it showing an error the namespace NaturalSortComparer could not found Mark Benovsky

Comment: Is there any way to move the backed textures in real time Mark Benovsky

Comment: There are two voids to switch the lightmaps in thr class from that example, before that you need to add the script to object and apply your lightmaps. This is the basics of unity workflow

Comment: Now you need to call methods from that script on that object

Comment: Using either buttons with assigned methods of that script, or pass script to your controller and call methods from it

Comment: Not sure about it working in the latest version of unity. But seems ok, there are many options to do this. He is changing the lightmaps on buttons.

Comment: My lighting data is not changing over there how to fix this?

Comment: Seems that easier for you will be using of dynamic lights, not static. Yes you need to apply texture in editor, just like you sent in that video. And then call methods to change the textures

Comment: Link to LightMapSwitcher is dead.